# XDocument to get the attribute of a preprocessing instruction

Tags: xml, linq

i want to access a preprocessing instruction "mso-infoPathSolution"  and which has an attribute href and assign a url to it say http://www.msn.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:XMLtool:-myXSD-2013-06-22T17-00-48" solutionVersion="1.0.0.457" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0"  href="" ?>
```

I need to use the XDocument class. How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Using VB.NET I was able to determine a processing instruction is encoded as an `XProcessingInstruction` and it is simply broken into

- `Target` (`mso-infoPathSolution` in your example), and
- `Data` (the rest of the `name="value"` pairs, unparsed),
- both `String`s.

So you need to check for an existing `href="..."`, adjust it if present and add it otherwise:

```vb
Dim xpi = xDoc.Nodes.OfType(Of XProcessingInstruction) _
          .Where(Function(p) p.Target = "mso-infoPathSolution").First
Dim re = New Regex("href=""([^""]*)""")
If re.IsMatch(xpi.Data) Then
  xpi.Data = re.Replace(xpi.Data, "href=""" & Url & """")
Else
  xpi.Data &= " href=""" & Url & """"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#:
1. Access the XProcessingInstruction(s) of the XDocument
2. Look at the following example how to access and change the processing string:
[MSDNlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction.data.aspx)

(Read the full article or scroll to "Examples")